# How to create mysql user with CREATE USER grant but without access to new databases?

Tags: mysql, users

I need mysql **admin_user** (not root user) which can create **write_user** with permissions: CREATE, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE and SELECT.

**admin_user** and **write_user** have access to **main_db**.

**write_user** will create **user_db** and only he can access to that db.

If I want that **admin_user** can create new user with some permissions, **admin_user** has to be created "WITH GRANT OPTION" but then he has access to all databases.

Question: How to create mysql user with CREATE USER grant but without access to new databases?

Answer (score 1):

With the GRANT command, you can use the ON keyword to set [table privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-table-privileges) for users.

For example: `GRANT ALL ON user_db to 'write_user'@'localhost'`